# Sort folder full of shortcuts by Destination property in Details view?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, shortcuts, sorting

### scenario

I'm on **Windows 8**.

I have some folders that contain `.lnk` files.

---

### problem

I would like to know if I can sort the files by the destination in the *Details view* column of the explorer. I can't find any detail attribute to sort `.lnk` files by their "destination" property.

---

### question

How I could sort the .lnk files by one of these two properties?:

[image: hard-to-read screencap showing properties dialog]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `Link Target` column.

Comment: Thanks, omg the original translation of "Link target" to my language in the windows explorer is too silly to find it. "Vincular destino", thanks again.